# Using Vuex and the Composition API, is there a way to access reactive properties?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, reactive-programming, vuex, vue-composition-api

If I design my component like this:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="increment">Count is: {{ store.getters.count }}</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { reactive } from "@vue/composition-api";
import store from "../store";

export default {
  name: "Count",

  setup() {
    const state = reactive({
      store
    });
    const increment = () => {
      store.dispatch.increment();
    };
    return {
      ...state,
      increment
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

And my store is defined like this:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
import { createDirectStore } from "direct-vuex";

Vue.use(Vuex);

const {
  store,
  rootActionContext,
  moduleActionContext,
  rootGetterContext,
  moduleGetterContext
} = createDirectStore({
  state: {
    count: 0
  },
  getters: {
    count: state => state.count
  },
  mutations: {
    increment(state) {
      state.count++;
    }
  },
  actions: {
    increment(context) {
      context.commit("increment");
    }
  }
});

// Export the direct-store instead of the classic Vuex store.
export default store;

// The following exports will be used to enable types in the
// implementation of actions and getters.
export {
  rootActionContext,
  moduleActionContext,
  rootGetterContext,
  moduleGetterContext
};

// The following lines enable types in the injected store '$store'.
export type AppStore = typeof store;
declare module "vuex" {
  interface Store<S> {
    direct: AppStore;
  }
}
```

Is there any way I can access the count better than `{{ store.getters.count }}` in the template? Ideally, I'd like to just access it like `{{ count }}`, but it seems like only `store` is reactive. In other words, if I dispatch the increment action, ``{{ count }}` doesn't update, even if I try to define count in various ways. Here's one thing I've tried:

```
  setup() {
    const state = reactive({
      store,
      count: store.getters.count
    });
    const increment = () => {
      store.dispatch.increment();
    };
    return {
      ...state,
      count: state.count,
      increment
    };
  }
```

Why isn't `{{ count }}` reactive in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`count: store.getters.count` means that you're storing the current value of `store.getters.count` as the default value of your state `count`.

That means it won't be reactive. Notice that `count` in the store is a function.

You could try making your state `count` a computed property instead so it would properly update.

I haven't tried the Composition API yet, but I hope I could help.

Comment: If I defined computed like this `count: computed(() => store.getters.count)` then {{ count }} is still not reactive.

Comment: You shouldn't put `count` inside `reactive`. Instead, make it a variable:

`const count = computed(() => store.getters.count)`

Then include it in your return statement:

`return { ..., count }`

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: You can put `count` inside a `reactive` state. Then: `return { state }` and in the template: `{{ state.count }}`. @bkinsey808

Comment: not working here, working in some places but not on others.